# Prisma doesn't return timezone

Tags: node.js, time, timezone, prisma

Database view:

[image]

Prisma schema:

```
model TableX {
  id        String         @id @default(uuid())
  startTime DateTime?      @db.Timetz()
  endTime   DateTime?      @db.Timetz()
  createdAt DateTime       @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime       @updatedAt
}
```

Response from API:

[image]

I expect to get the time with the time zone

Comment: Is this on postgres?

Comment: Yes, it's on Postgres

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `findMany`, that's a known bug of prisma: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7917

Comment: "Include" is related to the issue? See the place where I trying to get the fields https://github.com/Alerki/alerki/blob/main/api/src/module/user/user.service.ts#L90